# Fit image in DIV on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to show an image that fits in a div tag. This code works fine in Chrome but when I visualize it on Internet Explorer 8 I get a cropped image. This is my code

```
.grid{
    background:url('./images/grid.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:730px;
    height:647px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```
<div id="pointer_div" onclick="point_it(event)" class="grid">
...
</div>
```

Don't know if it helps but I gotta use

```
<!DOCTYPE html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//en">
```

Comment: How large is the image? Perhaps a JS Fiddle might help?

Answer (score 3):

The attribute `background-size` doesn't work in IE8.

You should try to add a `<img>` tag inside your div and use `max-width: 100%;` on the `<img>`.

http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: Why would you need `max-height`? height should adjust itself with the `max-width: 100%;`. If for some reason the height doesn't adjust, use `height: auto;`

Comment: Sometimes the images are larger in height but not in width and thus may not fit the width, In those cases, using `max-height` makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `background-size` is not supported by IE8